# rmarkdown: Custom indentation with static and dynamic content

Tags: text, formatting, r-markdown, indentation

I generate text with dynamic and static content. I would like to achieve this

[image]

(the dynamic content "Apples", "Gagaga ....." should be justified unlike in the picture. I just dont know how to achieve this in Writer)

I would like to achieve the indentation of the dynamic content.

I tried the following solutions but they don't work

````
---
title: ""
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

df<-data.frame(name=c("Apples", "Gagagagagagaga Long Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."))

```


Static content: `r df$name[1] `
\
\
Static content: `r df$name[2] `



\begingroup
\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Static content: &  `r df$name[1] `\\
Static content: &  `r df$name[2] `\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
````

Comment: When you say "Writer", are you referring to the [Accessible RMarkdown Writer](http://www.arowtool.com/#:~:text=About,easier%20for%20people%20with%20disabilities.)? Additionally, I assume you mean that you're looking to create a hanging indent? Lastly, you have `pdf_document` in the YAML. If you change output formats, the way to do this will change. Is this the only output you're concerned with?

Comment: I mean Libreoffice Writer, with wich I made this screenshot. I am only interested in PDF output. Yes. Normal Ident for the static and then hanging ident for the dynamic content